# Semantic UI Slider javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm testing out a [simple image slider](https://codepen.io/yowainwright/pen/GoggrV) for my rails app but it's not working, the images stack on top of each other instead.

```
<div class="slider slider1">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide-item item1">
      </div>
      <div class="slide-item item2"> 
      </div>
      <div class="slide-item item3">
      </div>
      <div class="slide-item item4">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried putting this in my application.js

```
 $('.slider').glide({
      autoplay: false,
      arrowsWrapperClass: 'slider-arrows',
      arrowRightText: '',
      arrowLeftText: ''
    });
```

I have the necessary gems installed and required semantic-ui in my application.js

Comment: See for console errors

Comment: rails console not showing any errors @Shubh

Comment: browser console I mean here

Comment: the error says 'TypeError: $(...).glide is not a function'

Comment: You havenot included the  js library or its not being loaded ,in which the `glide() `is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming to your example, you add slider library from outer resource.

Just add this script to your application layout.

```
javascript_include_tag "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.glide/1.0.6/jquery.glide.min.js"
```

Which populates your code with such html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.glide/1.0.6/jquery.glide.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE

Also wrap your `glide()` function call into `document.ready()`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').glide({
      autoplay: false,
      arrowsWrapperClass: 'slider-arrows',
      arrowRightText: '',
      arrowLeftText: ''
    });
});
```

Or if you're using `turbolinks`, wrap it such case:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.slider').glide({
    autoplay: false,
    arrowsWrapperClass: 'slider-arrows',
    arrowRightText: '',
    arrowLeftText: ''
  });
});
```

Comment: @sokoine I've updated my answer with additional js.

Comment: reloaded and everything disappears, in the web console i'm getting this error 'jQuery is not defined'

Comment: @sokoine Do you have `jquery-rails` installed and required?

Comment: putting //= require jquery above //= require_tree . in my application.js fixed all the errors showing in the web console, but the image slider is still not working, the images are still stacked on top of each other

Comment: @sokoine What about stylesheets? Does them required too in your application.css?

Comment: with the example i tried with from codepen they didn't include any css files. I've just tried with another example with css files and it's working now,thanks for the help!